# Powershell - How can I test the result of my command?

Tags: powershell

Sorry for this stupid question but I don't know how to simply test the result of my command (it returns an object)!

Here is my command:

```
$command = Get-ADUser -Server "MyServer" -Filter 'Name -eq "test"' -SearchBase "DC=MyDomain,DC=COM" -Properties badpwdcount,lockedout | Select-Object LockedOut
```

I just want to test the result like this :

```
if($command -eq $true){
   write-host "OK"
}
```

When I try this command to see the result :

```
write-host $command
```

I get "**@{LockedOut=True}**". So, I have tried to change also my condition like :

```
if($command -eq "@{LockedOut=True}"){
   write-host "OK"
}
```

But it's not working...

Comment: `$command.LockedOut -eq $true` (or just `$command.LockedOut`)

Comment: Thank you, this is working !

Comment: Posted a proper answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `Write-Host $command` outputs `@{LockedOut=True}`, it's because `Select-Object LockedOut` produces a new object with a `LockedOut` property.

Either change your `Select-Object` statement to use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter:

```
$command = Get-ADUser -Server "MyServer" -Filter 'Name -eq "test"' -SearchBase "DC=MyDomain,DC=COM" -Properties badpwdcount,lockedout | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LockedOut
if($command){
    # "test" user is locked out
}
```

or inspect the `LockedOut` property:

```
if($command.LockedOut){
    # "test" user is locked out
}
```

As you can see, the `-eq $true` comparison inside an `if` statement is redundant

---

Be aware that you may get unexpected results if you have multiple users with the name `test` in your directory. If you're locating users by username, you should filter on the `SAMAccountName` property (which is guaranteed to be unique per-domain):

```
$command = Get-ADUser -Server "MyServer" -Filter 'SAMAccountName -eq "test"' -SearchBase "DC=MyDomain,DC=COM" -Properties badpwdcount,lockedout | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LockedOut
if($command){
    # "test" user is locked out
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is a very constructive response! I will accept your answer when I can, bye!